# Laravel 5.x Eloquent method to update, create or delete dynamic input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dynamicform

I have a dynamic form element (say names of book titles) that a user can add or delete in the view. *Creation* is a breeze because all book models are new when the request arrives in the controller for saving to the database. During *updating*, if all book models are just left the same, modified or new ones are added, I can do the task with [`updateOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods) where all three cases are satisfied.

The problem now is when the user chooses to remove a book in the view; Laravel tries to save the deleted model:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'column_name' cannot be null

Is there an `updateCreateOrDelete` method or similar for this? I do not want to delete all books in the DB and re-create them because that is lazy and not recommended if the system has an audit system.

Basically I have an array of inputs that can be added or deleted:

1. if anything is updated then just update their DB entry;
2. if `n` are added, then create these new `n` values;
3. if `m` are deleted, then delete these `m` values from the DB

Comment: A bit of code would go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care about your constraints. Laravel won't delete your model if there is something that depends on it. Consider using delete on cascade in your migration or allow your dependency to be nullable.

Comment: cascade is definitely the path.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are receiving is specifically because your column is not nullable.

To fix this you would want to create a new migration an alter your table like so:

```
Schema::table('table', function ($table) {
    $table->string('column_name')->nullable();
});
```